# Error en llenar datos de recorset a arraylist java

Tags: java, arraylist, recordset

tengo estas lineas de codigo en el que estoy tratando de cargar datos de una tabla en myslq a un arraylist, ejecuta pero al extraer los datos supuestamente cargados en el arraylist me sale una lista de datos que no son los que tiene la tabla:

```
    public java.util.List<Codigos> llenarArrays(String sql){
                java.util.List<Codigos> listado = new java.util.ArrayList<Codigos>();
                int x=0;
                try{
                    ps=VentanaPrincipal.PantallaPrincipal.CONEXION.getConnection().prepareStatement(sql);
                    rs=ps.executeQuery();
                    while(rs.next()){
                        Codigos codigo= new Codigos();
                        codigo.setCodigo(rs.getString(2));
                        codigo.setDescripcion(rs.getString(3));
                        listado.add(codigo);
                        System.out.println(listado.get(x));
                        x++;
                    }
                    rs.close();
                    ps.close();
                    
                }catch(SQLException e){
                       System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                }
                
            return listado;
        }
```

> La clase Codigos

```
    public class Codigos {
        private String codigo;
        private String descripcion;
    
        public String getCodigo() {
            return codigo;
        }
    
        public void setCodigo(String codigo) {
            this.codigo = codigo;
        }
    
        public String getDescripcion() {
            return descripcion;
        }
    
        public void setDescripcion(String descripcion) {
            this.descripcion = descripcion;
        }
    }
```

> Aqui este bloque que extraera los datos del arraylist

```
    private void llenaCodigos(){
            gestion=new Clases.GestionDatos();  
            String sql="SELECT * FROM base_codoper "
                    + "where id_tequipo='TE08' ";
            gestion=new Clases.GestionDatos();
            //listado=new java.util.ArrayList<>();
            listado=gestion.llenarArrays(sql);
        
        
    }
```

```
pero al ejecutar me arroja estos valores

Clases.Codigos@76543499
Clases.Codigos@451022a1
Clases.Codigos@7508bc5d
Clases.Codigos@67c3d92d
Clases.Codigos@30e4d9b0
Clases.Codigos@74a5e027
Clases.Codigos@44ff40ba
```

> Son datos incomprensibles, alguien que sepa porque pasa esto por >favor, quizas estoy enredandome no entiendo, o si hay manera de >simplificarlo, lo que quiero es extraer los datos de una tabla a un >arraylist para luego hacer consultas y extraer datos del arraylist >mediante un indice
> Agradezco su apoyo de antemano

Comment: Hola, Bienvenido(a) a SOes. El código no debería mostrarse a través de imágenes, recuerda que no todos podemos verlo. Te invito a que edites tu pregunta y pongas el código con su respectivo formato. Mira [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida y tengas respuestas cuanto antes.

Comment: Hola R.Hinostroza, vamos por partes, primero te sugiero que edites tu pregunta, elimines las imágenes y agreges el código y los mensajes recibidos como texto, por otro lado, sin ver la clase **Codigos** es muy difícil que alguien pueda resolver tu problema, osea, agregala.

Answer (score 0):

Deberías iterarlo de esta forma:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Codigos> lista = tuObjeto.llenarArrays("select * from codigos");
        for(Codigos codigo: lista){
            System.out.println(codigo.getDescripcion());
        }
    }
```

o ya que muestras tu código, solo modifica esta línea: `System.out.println(listado.get(x));` por `System.out.println(listado.get(x).getDescripcion());` o el objeto que quieres leer.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, pero podrias explicarme un poco mejor, o si tienes una manera de como extraer datos de una tabla en mysql y cargarlo a un arraylist

Comment: Creo que tu consulta a la base de datos está bien, en todo caso deberías mostrar la clase o método de donde llamas a ese código que muestras.